# Passing data from one PHP page to another PHP Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a program that I'm making that takes a database gets the top 5 rows from that database and presents it to a user when a button is clicked on the website I have made. I was able to get the database data to print on the page where the button was clicked, but I want it to be printed to another page that I have created. Here is my code so far for the main page with the buttons and the PHP code to get the database information(the file is called file1.php):

```
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Testing SQL DB</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function myAjax () {
            $.ajax( { type : 'POST',
              data : { },
              url  : 'query.php',              // <=== CALL THE PHP FUNCTION HERE.
              success: function ( data ) {
                document.getElementById("dbResult").innerHTML = data;   // Get the element with id="demo"
              },
              error: function ( xhr ) {
                alert( "error" );
              }
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <style>
        h1
        {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 45px;
        }

        .radio-input
        {
            font-size: 35px;
        }
        .radio
        {
            font-size: 45px;
            display: block;
            vertical-align: top;
            margin-right: 3%;
            margin-bottom: 30%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .buttons 
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .jumbotron {
            position: relative;
            background: #dca7ea url("dogGif.gif") center center;  
            width: 50%;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            height: 50%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .jumbotron2 
        {
              min-height: 50%;  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
              min-height: 40vh; /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */
              background-color: #fb6f74;
              display: flex;
              align-items: center;
        }
        #dbResult
        {
            text-align: center;

        }
    </style>

    <body style = "background-color: #dca7ea;">
        <h1>Pet Name generator! The perfect name for your pet.</h1>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
           </div> 
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron2">
            <div class="container">
                  <div class="radio">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="girl">Girl</label>
                      <label><input type="radio" name="boy">Boy</label>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Normal names</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Specialty names</button> 
                      <a href="file2.php" target="_blank"><button id="submit_btn" onclick="myAjax()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Random name</button></a> 
                      <p method="post" action="file2.php" id="dbResult" name="databaseNames">No results </p>
                  </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My query.php file is as follows:

```
<?php 
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','names_tbl');
    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM names_tbl.general_names LIMIT 5;";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<u>".$row['Name']."</u>";            
    }
?>
```

Finally, my file I want the data to be transferred on is giving an error saying "Undefined index: dbNames" in file2.php(this is the line in which it's giving me the error in my second file)

```
          <?php
             echo("Names: " . $_POST['dbNames'] . "<br/>\n");
          ?>
```

No SO posts have been able to help me, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have already looked at these posts and nothing has worked for me. I wouldn't have posted the question if I didn't look at the popular posts with my question

Comment: You aren't passing any data via Ajax

Comment: Thats the part I don't understand how to do

Comment: Do a Google Search for Ajax send variables to php script. You should find something

Comment: You are not attaching data to your post request, `data : { }` is empty, while it should be `data : {'dbNames': 'My data I want to attach'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not embed an ajax request to a function. It strips off a large portion of flexibility of something called "events".

You want to request data when the user clicks on the button:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#normalnames').click(function(){
        $.ajax( { 
          type : 'POST',
          data : { type: 'normalnames' },
          url  : 'query.php',
          success: function ( data ) {
            $('#dbResult').html(data);
          },
          error: function ( xhr ) {
            alert( "error" );
          }
        });
      });

      $('#specialnames').click(function(){
        //etc
      });
    });
</script>

<button id="normalnames" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Normal names</button>
<button id="specialnames" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Normal names</button>
```

And on the PHP side of things:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['type'])){
    if($_POST['type'] == 'normalnames'){
      // make normal names query
    } elseif($_POST['type'] == 'specialnames'){
      // make special names query
    } else {
      die('incorrect request');
    }
  } else {
    die('unknown request');
  }
?>
```

Now you want to enlist data in the dbresponse div:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[] = "<li>".$row['Name']."</li>";            
}

echo '<ul>' . implode($data) . '</ul>';
```

That would be the gist of it, perhaps its better to work with returning with json (`echo json_encode($data)` without the html tags) as javascript can traverse though it and append it to the list.

To use that data on another page, use [sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).